# Create SQL server db, table, import programatically using Visual Studio 2012,C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm losing the way when I'm look after controlling db and then populate it in aspx gridview, so I prefer to do this within Visual Studio.

I have multiple text files that I want to create for them SQL Server db and create and load the text files data into db tables based on column value.

```
[if text file column a value = 1 then 
 if sql db table 1 exist import else
 create sql db table 1 and import]
```

All tables would be with the same structure.
If you direct me how to do this or guide me to a good tutorial. I read that I need to add a reference sqlmdo something to create db within vs but as it's not there I downloaded it but I didn't know how to add it to the assemblies. Main idea is to control and do this using vs....really thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the need to import the text file into a table a one-time deal, or something that is part of your application that needs to happen repeatedly?  If it's a one-time deal, then ctrl-c, ctrl-v from perhaps an Excel view is often times your best friend if the data is constructed and presented properly and the table already exists.  If a feature of your application, then that's a different answer altogether.  I guess more information on your case is needed.

Comment: it happen repeatedly. I'm having now the data for 6 years in 12 large text files then I will need to import data daily. but later on, rarely I will need to create table.

Comment: Ok, hopefully i framed this right: it's basically a database maintenance issue that you want to automate, but using VS to help with the automation task.

Comment: Yes, you are right brother bob. More to mention is the number of tables to be created currently is approximately 160 table. As later I'm going to apply some calculation with the data. appreciate any support...thanks.

Comment: what is the format of these text files?  CSV?  If so, is the properties of this csv known (ie comma vs tab separated, quotes, line breaks, etc)?

Comment: sorry for late, i have them in txt format and I could have them in csv and excel format. delemiter is comma. Thanks for the support bob.. please assist and encourage.I could import them to excel easy and I did create access db and tables and import as what I need now using excel vba but for the size and the need for asp.net I prefer to do this via VS,C# and I searching around I don't really see it easy as in vba.